# Mapping between MIMIC-II v2.6's meditems' itemids and MIMIC-III d_items?

Tags: mimic-iii

I wonder whether there exists a mapping between MIMIC-II v2.6's meditems' itemids and MIMIC-III d_items.

Comment: Franck, can you add link to your question so we know what you are referring to.

Comment: @magdmartin isn't the tag enough?

Comment: I've no idea what mimic-iii is ...

Comment: @magdmartin The MIMIC III (Multiparameter Intelligent Monitoring in Intensive Care) database contains physiologic signals and vital signs time series captured from patient monitors, and comprehensive clinical data obtained from hospital medical information systems, for tens of thousands of Intensive Care Unit (ICU) patients at Beth Israel Deaconess Medical Center. MIMIC can be downloaded from this [website](https://mimic.physionet.org/).

Comment: I guess this is not my topic of choice. It is not the first time I stumbled on a mimic-iii question when reviewing the close vote review queue.